# 2 child process does not display a message

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to learn programming on and I don’t understand why I can't get child 2 to print hello. I have also closed both read and write ends of the pipe for the parent because I don’t want the parent to communicate. Any help is much appreciated.

```
 int main ()

{

   int fd[2];

   pid_t child_pid, child_pid1;


if (pipe(fd) < 0)
{
    printf("Pipe error");   
}

child_pid = fork (); // child 1
if (child_pid != 0)
{
    printf("im child 1");       
    dup2 (fd[1], STDIN_FILENO);
    printf("greetings");


    child_pid1 = fork (); //child 2
    if (child_pid1 != 0)
    {   
        printf("im child 2");
        dup2(fd[0], STDOUT_FILENO);
        printf("hello");

    }

    else if (child_pid1 > 0) //Parent Code
    {
        close (fd[0]);
        close (fd[1]);

    }
}

return 0;

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `if` clause is wrong.

```
child_pid = fork (); // child 1
if (child_pid != 0)
{
    printf("im child 1");       
}
```

This is not the child but the parent. If it is the child, then pid will be 0, only on the parent you have `child_pid != 0`.

The same happens in the second `if` clause as well.

You should do `if(child_pid == 0)` in both cases, if you want that code to be executed in the child process.

Comment: You should also remove that `dup2` calls.